# Bin data into quantiles using break points from one group

Tags: r, datatable, quantile

For each level of `ts_id`, how to cut ALL data into 2 bins, using the median value of `s1` computed using rows with `ex_id == 1`?

```
DT = data.table(

     ts_id = c(rep(1,15),rep(2,15)),
     ex_id = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,10),rep(1,5),rep(2,10)),
     s1 = rnorm(30)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help.  Specify the `i` with logical expression (`ex_id == 1`), grouped by 'ts_id', `split` the 's1' by a logical vector created by comparing the values of 's1' with the `median` of 's1' (here, it is changed to numeric index)

```
DT[ex_id==1,  list(split(s1, (s1 >= median(s1)) + 1)), ts_id]
```

NOTE: The expected output is not clear